# create-react-app cicd in bitbucket Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: reactjs, node.js, bitbucket, cicd

We're work with Bitbucket's CI/CD pipelines with create-react-app,
there is a strange problum,I just push a commit without add any package,
then I got failed in CI/CD.

What’s even more strange is that the same error will appear when executing the once successful pipeline.

here is the build messages.

```
npm run build
1m 47s
+ npm run build
> traceability@1.0.0 build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Failed to compile.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
```

This is the success case before

```
npm run build
2m 4s
+ npm run build
> traceability@1.0.0 build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Compiled successfully.
File sizes after gzip:
  811.42 kB  build/static/js/main.d953cb8c.js
  2.99 kB    build/static/css/main.a4671051.css
  1.78 kB    build/static/js/787.abd4bb9f.chunk.js
The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
Consider reducing it with code splitting: 
You can also analyze the project dependencies: 
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /traceability/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
Find out more about deployment here:
  https://cra.link/deployment
```

This is the bitbucket.pipeline.yml

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &test-step
        name: Test
        image: node:alpine
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
    - step: &lint-step
        name: Lint
        image: node:alpine
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install eslint
          - npx eslint src
    - step: &build-step
        name: Build and Test
        image: node:alpine
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install --only=production --ignore-scripts
          - npm test
          - npm run build
        artifacts:
          - build/**

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step: *test-step
        - step: *lint-step
  branches:
    main:
      - parallel:
          - step: *build-step
          - step: *lint-step
          - step:
              name: Security Scan
              script:
                - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - echo ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASS} | docker login --username "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin
            - DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE=${DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}
            - docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest || true
            - docker build --cache-from ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest -f docker/production/Dockerfile -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${BITBUCKET_COMMIT} -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest .
            - docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}
            - docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
```